# Error with Graph API Call via PowerApp - Office365.FindMeetingTimes when > 20 rooms

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, powerapps, microsoft-graph-calendar

We are now getting an error within our Book A Room powerapp when trying to find available meeting times.  The error has only started since we added a new room which takes us to 21 rooms in our Office 365. The error is as follows:
[image: error]

The issue seems to be that in the API request all 21 rooms are included in the requiredAttendees json attribute. Once I remove the newly added room on Office365 the error goes away.

All rooms in the catalogue need to be included in the request to see whether they are available for booking but is this limit of 20 a hard limit on the API side? If so, what alternatives do I have?

Comment: Can you publish a sample of the code you use for this request?

Comment: @FerronSW, the code in the PowerApp that makes the call is as follows:
`code
Office365.FindMeetingTimes({RequiredAttendees: AllRoomsConnector, IsOrganizerOptional: true, 
        Start: StartDateTimeUTC, End: EndDateTimeUTC, MeetingDuration: DateDiff(StartDateTime, EndDateTime, Minutes),
        MinimumAttendeePercentage: "10", ActivityDomain: "Unrestricted"})`

Comment: Thanks! What happens if you switch out the RequiredAttendees for your AllRoomsConnector with Resource attendees? https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/connectors/office365connector/#find-meeting-times

Comment: @FerronSW, Within the powerapp it gives me an error when I try to add RequiredAttendees to the call, [here](https://i.imgur.com/DIjUWI3.png) is the method signature for Office365.FindMeetingTimes within the powerapp

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the Office365.FindMeetingTimes() endpoint, but if this is a limitation of the API, then it sounds like you may need to implement a sort of paging in your app. The first time the app calls FindMeetingTimes(), you'll have to pass in the first 20 rooms. Then if the user isn't satisfied with the proposed times, they can initiate a "find more times" feature that will call FindMeetingTimes() with the next 20 rooms. I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it could be a workaround.